# Maps Engine map in Android application

Tags: android, google-maps, google-maps-android-api-2

I want to show a google map of a place with custom markers for different places. I want to be able to edit these markers without updating the app. Best way to do this according to me is using Maps Engine layer in Maps api for android. I have tried searching but haven't gotten an answer.

If there is a better way to do what I am trying to achieve please suggest me that. Let me know if updating/adding markers is not possible without updating the app.

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can pull maps engine data into your app via the API and populate markers on your map view.
Google give some great examples in the API docs @ [Maps Engine API docs](https://developers.google.com/maps-engine/documentation/public-read)

You could also roll a home brew solution and store your marker data on a server and have your application check for updates each run or daily.